# How to find hot spots for parallelism in .net 4?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

So many of us would probably start with implementing something in non-parallel way and later need to refactor the code and employ parallelism. Is there any theory or suggestion about how to find hot spot functions or pieces of code for parallelism effectively.

For example, I may have the following piece of code in non-parallel style:

```
int[] data = new int[1000000];    // Just a big trunk of data.

// Here is just a procedure on the trunk of data, performing repeated work.
void SequentialProcedure(){
    for(int  i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) data[i] += rand.Next();
}
```

For a guy like me without much parallelism experience, at the first glance, it would look like a function that may be applied with some fancy parallelism skill:

```
int[] data = new int[1000000];    // The same big trunk of data.

// A parallel implementation.
void ParallelProcedure(){
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, data.Length),
        range => {
            for(int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++) data[i] += rand.Next();
        }
    );
}
```

OK. Even though I read something and know that the actual task to add a random number to each vector element is small comparing to the cost of creating delegates and use ranges to make each parallel task more meaty, the parallel version is still slower than the sequential version. At this point, I will get lost: so the SequentialProcedure is simply a function not suitable for parallelism? or the way I try to parallelize it is just wrong? is there any suggestions, guidelines from gurus that we can follow on spotting where parallelism would take more effect and where parallelism would simply be a waste of time?

Thank you very much for any help.

Edit:

In order to make each iteration more meaty, I add a second level iteration. So the sequential code becomes:

```
int[] data = new int[100];

void SequentialProcedure(){
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 500000; j++) data[i] = rand.Next(j, Int32.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

And the parallel version becomes:

```
int[] data = new int[100];
void ParallelProcedure(){
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, data.Length),
    range => {
        for(int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 500000; j++) data[i] = rand.Next(j, Int32.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

It is interesting to see that even now each outer iteration has enough work to do, the parallel procedure is still almost 4 times slower than the sequential procedure on my machine.

Is it possible some memory allocation/caching issue?

Edit: apparently, it is less likely a memory issue that cause the parallel to slow down in the above example. Really need to figure out the reason...

Answer (score 1):

I found the place where it is slowing down. It is the shared Random object that mess up the performance. When I make rand thread located, I get the speed up. Parallel version is roughly 4 times faster than the sequential version on my four-core machine. But still the question is well opened for any insightful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Profile. When you find something slow, then see if it's doing parallelizable operations. Those are your "hot spots for parallellism."

Comment: This only addresses half the question. He has a function he thinks should parallelize easily, yet it goes twice as slow when using TPL. So, why?

Comment: Thanks Gabe. To Domenic, yes, profile helps to spot on slow code. But the skill is needed to "insightfully see" if the operations are parallelizable and how to "insighfully see" is what I am seeking for help.

Comment: Well I would imagine the reason the above function doesn't parallelize well is exactly the reason you give in your post: viz. "the actual task to add a random number to each vector element is small comparing to the cost of creating delegates and use ranges to make each parallel task more meaty." Things that aren't slow don't parallelize well.

Comment: So you imply that, for time-consuming functions which do many iterations of small work, there is not much benefit you can get from by parallelize the iterations?

Comment: For parallelism to be useful there has to be a reasonable amount of computationally intensive work for it to farm out to worker threads. Otherwise, the overhead of partitioning, collating, and coordinating the extra threads may actually slow things down. --- quoted (with slightly modification) from Joe Albahari. This may be the reason why in my example code, parallel version is slower than non-parallel one.

Comment: Yes, that's my implication. Maybe if you batched it into, say, 4 worker threads instead of 100? You could experiment.